# decrement incrementer while looping

Tags: java, for-loop

iI'm trying to decrement an incrementer when a condition is met in a java loop, example:
Suppose we have an ArrayList containing many (ascending sorted) Integers, when i meet 2 or more subsequent equal Integers i wanna merge them:

```
for(int i=0; i<intArr.size();i++){

 if(intArr.get(i).equals(intArr.get(i+1))){
    intArr.set(i,(intArr.get(i) + intArr.get(i+1)));
    intArr.remove(i+1);
    i--;
 }

}
```

A more concrete example at the bottom of the message.

This will fail, the incrementer (i) will be "temporarily" set to (i--), but when it will go back in the for line, it will have its original value.
HDo you have any idea how to decrement i so that at the next iteration i can still compare (i==i+1?)
Thank you

```
public class Test
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intArray.add(1);
    intArray.add(2);
    intArray.add(3);
    intArray.add(4);
    intArray.add(4);
    intArray.add(4);
    intArray.add(5);
    intArray.add(6);
    intArray.add(7);
    intArray.add(8);
    intArray.add(9);
    intArray.add(9);
    intArray.add(9);
    intArray.add(9);
    intArray.add(10);
    intArray.add(11);
    intArray.add(12);
    intArray.add(12);

    for (int i = 0; i < (intArray.size() - 1); i++)
    {
      if (intArray.get(i).equals(intArray.get(i + 1)))
      {
        intArray.set(i, (intArray.get(i) + intArray.get(i + 1)));
        intArray.remove(i + 1);
        i--;
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.size(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println(intArray.get(i));
    }
  }

}
```

prints:

```
1
2
3
8
4
5
6
7
8
18
18
10
11
24
```

Comment: You are wrong: `i--` **will decrement**, and it will remain decremented in the next iteration.

Comment: @FarukSahin Assigning `i--` to a variable is the same as assigning `i` to that variable.

Comment: Do you really want to decrement i or just not increment i (what your code is doing)?

Comment: Please check my initial post again, i have added a more concrete example, as you can see from the final print, the three four (4) are merged only once, the third one is not being merged because its skipped by the loop.

Comment: You would actually need to increment once more instead of decrementing, because the next index is removed in your condition, so you want this to be skipped right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when it find the first two 4's it changes them to 8. Now, when the third 4 comes, the array is

1
2
3
**8
4**
5
6
.
.
.

so this  time, it checks whether (8 == 4), which is false. So it skips the next 4!

Comment: Oh, i really did not think about it!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of juggling the indices, I recommend using `Iterator.remove` to collapse streaks:

```
final List<Integer> intArr = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(1,1,2,2,2,4,5,7));
Integer previous = null;
for (Iterator<Integer> iter = intArr.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  final int curr = iter.next();
  if (previous == null) previous = curr;
  else if (previous == curr) iter.remove();
  else previous = curr;
}
System.out.println(intArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh boy... your coding style is not clean... will get a lot of errors this way.

1) You should not use auto-boxing. Especially not when it comes to comparisons with ==

2) When you write an example, add all the details so it can actually run (this also includes a lot of useful hints as to what backing lists you are using etc) [edit: I see you extended your question]

3) Get to understand the difference between ++i and i++ (not actually related, but might help in other situations

4) When [i] and [i+1] are equal, why jump back?

5) The backing list (in your case intArr) might not keep up the ordering when removing items from it.

6) Consider sets or maps for storing unique values. Use HashSet, or TreeSet to include sorting/ordering of elements

7) You still wanna use it the old-fashioned way, use while loops.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a while loop if your conditional variable is not incrementing in each for iteration. It also improves readability.

```
int i = 0;
while((i-1)<intArr.size())
{
  if(intArr.get(i).equals(intArr.get(i+1)))
  {
    intArr.set(i,(intArr.get(i) + intArr.get(i+1)));
    intArr.remove(i+1);
  }
  else
  {
    i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception when reaching the last object in the array: intArr.get(i+1)